# Whichs options in dns.lookup to get all addresses?

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm trying to use the `dns` module of `nodejs` to get all address associated with an hostname. My code is:

```
} else {
  var host = m[1];
  var options = {
    all: true
  }
  dns.lookup(host, options, function (err, addresses) {
    if (err) {
      var s = "Couldn't resolve hostname " + host + ". Skipping.";
      nba.sendMessage(msg.from.id, s.toString('utf8'));
    }
    else {
      var s = '';
      addresses.forEach(function (address) {
        s += host + " has " + address.family + " address " + address.address + "\n";
      });
      nba.sendMessage(msg.from.id, s.toString('utf8'));
    }
  });
}
```

I get the following error:

```
dns.js:91
      throw new Error('invalid argument: `family` must be 4 or 6');
            ^
Error: invalid argument: `family` must be 4 or 6
    at Object.exports.lookup (dns.js:91:13)
    at Object.exports.processMessage (/home/francesco/Dropbox/Informatica/Programmazione/MyPingBot/MessageProcessor.js:86:11)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/francesco/Dropbox/Informatica/Programmazione/MyPingBot/NodeBotAPI.js:75:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

But I don't get why. In the documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback) I read:

```
Alternatively, options can be an object containing these properties:

    family {Number} - The record family. If present, must be the integer 4 or 6. If not provided, both IP v4 and v6 addresses are accepted.
    hints: {Number} - If present, it should be one or more of the supported getaddrinfo flags. If hints is not provided, then no flags are passed to getaddrinfo. Multiple flags can be passed through hints by logically ORing their values. See supported getaddrinfo flags below for more information on supported flags.
    all: {Boolean} - When true, the callback returns all resolved addresses in an array, otherwise returns a single address. Defaults to false.

All properties are optional.
```

Comment: Your code worked for me with hardcoded value for host. Then I realized I was using node 4.2.1. It worked in my iojs v2.0 as well. Then I switched back to 0.10.33_1 and got the same issue. It seems like a bug in that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `all` option was added in [633a99084](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/633a9908487efadda6a86026a36d5325a28805c6), which first appeared in io.js v1.2.0. That also means any node v0.10 or v0.12 version will not have this feature.